# Error While Generating Access Token For Shopify App

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, shopify

I have built an app for Shopify Shops and it was working fine until yesterday. Link to the documentation followed to create a Shopify app: https://docs.shopify.com/api/authentication/oauth

But now there seems to be an error while generating an access token. I have been getting the error in response:

```
{"error":"795: unexpected token at 'code=<my-code>\u0026client_secret=<my-secret>\u0026client_id=<my-client-id>'"}
```

Here is the gist of code written in Google App Script.

```
function doPost(e)
{
    try
    {
        var client_id = e.parameter['client_id'];
        var client_secret = e.parameter['client_secret'];
        var code = e.parameter['code'];
        var shopUrl = e.parameter['shopUrl'];

        var headers = {
            "Accept":"application/json", 
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        };

        var payload = {
            "client_id" : client_id,
            "client_secret" : client_secret,
            "code": code
        };

        var options =
        {
            "method" : "POST",
            "payload" : payload,
            "headers" : headers,
            "muteHttpExceptions":true
        };

        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(shopUrl, options);
        var data = response.getContentText().split('"')[3];

        //response variable gives the following response
        // {"error":"795: unexpected token at 'code=<my-code>\u0026client_secret=<my-client-secret>\u0026client_id=<my-client-id>'"}

        return ContentService.createTextOutput(data).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
    }//try
    catch(e)
    {
        //log the exception
    }//catch
}//doPost
```

Did anybody encounter the same error? Please help

Comment: From what we can see it's receiving a token it cannot handle. You should post more of your source (specifically the portion that handles that) for us to be able to figure out why.

Comment: In addition to the source code, can you also add the exception?

Comment: Let me update the question

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that you requested to right URL, it just likes as 
  "https://[YOUR_SHOP_DOMAIN]/admin/oauth/access_token".
- Make sure that you gave right ID&secret.
- Check my PHP-code here for getting Shopify access-token: 
  [ShopifyClient.php](https://github.com/NguyenDuyPhong/shopify_api_php/blob/master/ShopifyAPI/ShopifyClient.php) (scroll to the function "getAccessToken")

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have checked everything over and over again. The reason why this happened because I have generated another ID & secret so the the old one does not work, I think workaround for this is to generate new access token with the help of refresh token